# How I can change JMenuItem alignment to right align

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jmenuitem

I have written a program in java with `netBeans` editor.

my form have a `jmenuBar` with some `jmenu` in right alignment.

for example `jmenu1` have some `jmenuItem`, i want right align all `jmenuitem`'s text.

when i change Horizontal alignment of them to right, text not shown when i run it.

```
menuItem1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

How i can do it?

http://upcity.ir/images/18431917276667197781.jpg

Comment: is 'Sub Menu' not right aligned now? You should experiment with different menu items of different lengths. At the moment the menu is as wide as the text

Comment: @MyNameIsTooCommon have to calculating that (read OPs name) there are used ComponetOrientaions.RTL too, maybe not, nobody knows, I added SSCCE with Image, because could be an interesting question, doeasn't matter of LTR or RTL ...

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10472124/1057230) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10503190/1057230) answer of mine. Might be, they be of some help :-)

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali do you think works with RTL Orientations

Comment: Yeah I guess dude, though, hadn't used JMenu that much. + up voted the question from my side, when I wrote my first comment, for more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
    JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Item ________ 2");
    JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("Item 3");

    item1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    item3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

It works for me. The problem might be in length of items - they are the same thus right alignment is not visible.